# BlazeMonster (AS3 VO/DTO Generation) support complex Java class?

Tags: java, mapping, blazeds, dto, value-objects

Can [BlazeMonster](http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/blazemonster/) generate AS3 Value Object/Data Transfer Object from complex Java classes without issue, like enum, generic, collection/set/list/map than contain other collection/set/list/map (few levels) without any issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not ask directly the guy who wrote it?

Comment: @Cornel Creanga, have asked. No answer. Will try myself and post the answer later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't generate Java generic collection correctly, E.g.

```
public Set<MyClass> objs;
```

it will generate

```
public var auths:java.util.Set;
```

It also can't generate Java enum correctly.